# How to validate content length of multipart form data in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, multipartform-data, form-data, content-length, http-content-length

I post `FormData` (including files) to a server that rejects requests with a content-length that exceeds a specific limit. I'd like to validate the content-length in my JavaScript client (browser) before doing a request that is doomed to be rejected. How do I get the content-length of my (`multipart/form-data`) encoded `FormData` object?

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('text', text);
formData.append('file', file);
if (getContentLength(formData) > limit) {
    alert('Content length limit is exceeded');
} else {
    fetch(url, { method: 'POST', body: formData });
}
```

---

**Edit:** Thanks for your answer, @Indgalante. Just using `length` of a string and `size` of a file does not calculate the correct content length.

```js
function getContentLength(formData) {
  const formDataEntries = [...formData.entries()]

  const contentLength = formDataEntries.reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    if (typeof value === 'string') return acc + value.length
    if (typeof value === 'object') return acc + value.size

    return acc
  }, 0)

  return contentLength
}

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('text', 'foo');
alert(`calculated content-length is ${getContentLength(formData)}`);
fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', { method: 'POST', body: formData });
```

You did not consider that the form data is encoded in the request. Thereby, i.a. boundary is added. The calculated content-length in the example is 3, but should be 138 in my Chrome browser

[image: chrome]

and 172 in my Firefox browser. I'm unsure how other browsers behave.

[image: Firefox]

Comment: Have you solved this? I face a related question in Safari.

Comment: @Soyaine Not really. I use an estimation as described in my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63471719/1065654

Answer (score 2):

I still don't know if it is possible to calculate the exact size, but you can at least try to estimate it:

```
/**
 * Estimate the content length of (multipart/form-data) encoded form data
 * object (sent in HTTP POST requests).
 * We do not know if you can get the actual content length.
 * Hence, it is estimated by this function.
 * As soon as {@link https://stackoverflow.com/q/62281752/1065654 this}
 * question is answered (correctly), the correct calculation should be used.
 *
 * @param formData
 */
function estimateContentLength(formData: FormData) {
    // Seems to be 44 in WebKit browsers (e.g. Chrome, Safari, etc.),
    // but varies at least in Firefox.
    const baseLength = 50; // estimated max value
    // Seems to be 87 in WebKit browsers (e.g. Chrome, Safari, etc.),
    // but varies at least in Firefox.
    const separatorLength = 115; // estimated max value
    let length = baseLength;
    const entries = formData.entries();
    for (const [key, value] of entries) {
        length += key.length + separatorLength;
        if (typeof value === 'object') {
            length += value.size;
        } else {
            length += String(value).length;
        }
    }
    return length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a async version that first converts the FormData into a Blob. from which you can retrieve the actual size that is going to be sent to the server.

So instead of posting the formdata you send the generated blob instead.

```js
async function test() {
  // Create some dummy data
  const fd = new FormData()
  fd.set('a', 'b')

  // acquire an actual raw bytes as blob of what the request would send
  const res = new Response(fd)
  const blob = await res.blob()

  blob.text && (
    console.log('what the actual body looks like'), 
    console.log(await blob.text())
  )

  // can't use own blob's type since spec lowercase the blob.type
  // so we get the actual content type
  const type = res.headers.get('content-type')

  // the acutal content-length size that's going to be used
  console.log('content-length before sending', blob.size)

  // verify
  const testRes = await fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', { 
    method: 'POST',
    body: blob, // now send the blob instead of formdata
    headers: { // use the real type (and not the default lowercased blob type)
      'content-type': type
    }
  })
  const json = await testRes.json()
  const headers = new Headers(json.headers)
  console.log('form that got posted:', JSON.stringify(json.form))
  console.log('content-length that was sent', headers.get('content-length'))
}

test()
```

However this don't work in IE, and Safari

- IE don't have fetch (but it's dead anyway)
- Safari has this bugs.

  - https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=161190
  - https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=212858
  - https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=171581

all doe, replacing the formdata with a polyfilled version such as https://github.com/jimmywarting/FormData might assist you with converting a formdata into a blob directly (synchronous) without using the fetch api (using `formData._blob()`). that is if you need wider browser support

Comment: imo i think this is kind of overkill, an estimate is also good enough.

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be [FormData.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries)
 so you can iterate over all your data and get a final content length.
We will also need a `spread operator` over an array or you could use `Array.from()` to convert the iterator returned by `.entries()` into a proper array.

Code example below, I didn't test it with files but let me know if you have any edge case with this one.

```
function getContentLength(formData) {
  const formDataEntries = [...formData.entries()]

  const contentLength = formDataEntries.reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    if (typeof value === 'string') return acc + value.length
    if (typeof value === 'object') return acc + value.size

    return acc
  }, 0)

  return contentLength
}
```

Comment: This does not consider the size of the boundary.